# Generate Label by First occurrence

Tags: python, pandas, multilabel-classification, find-occurrences

Below is a snapshot of my data frame, and I have a list of ID from 1 to N, with outcomes 1 or 0. What I am trying to do is to generate the Label and csum columns basic on the occurrence of the outcome in Python, how do I achieve this and loop through N Ids?

Label: the past 3 days when outcome 1 occur

csum: Keep Counting and sum 1 until 1 occurs, then reset again

My Dataset:

| ID | Date | Outcome |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-01 | 0 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-02 | 0 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-03 | 0 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-04 | 0 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-05 | 0 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-06 | 0 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-07 | 0 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-08 | 1 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-09 | 0 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-10 | 0 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-11 | 0 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-01 | 0 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-02 | 0 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-03 | 1 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-04 | 0 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-05 | 0 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-06 | 0 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-07 | 0 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-08 | 0 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-09 | 1 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-10 | 0 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-11 | 0 |

My Target Outcome:

| ID | Date | Outcome | Label | Csum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-01 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-02 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-03 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-04 | 0 | 0 | 4 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-05 | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-06 | 0 | lab1 | 6 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-07 | 0 | lab1 | 7 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-08 | 1 | lab1 | 8 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-09 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-10 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| ID_1 | 2021-01-11 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-01 | 0 | lab1 | 1 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-02 | 0 | lab1 | 2 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-03 | 1 | lab1 | 3 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-04 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-05 | 0 | 0 | 2 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-06 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-07 | 0 | lab1 | 4 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-08 | 0 | lab1 | 5 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-09 | 1 | lab1 | 6 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-10 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| ID_2 | 2021-01-11 | 0 | 0 | 2 |

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you add the desired outcome for your example data?

Comment: added back*,  my target columns are 'Label' and 'Csum'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use:

```
# identify the rows with a 1 in the next 3 rows (per group)
m = df[::-1].groupby('ID').rolling(3, min_periods=1)['Outcome'].max().droplevel(0)

# identify the rows where 0 restarts
df['Label'] = m.mask(m.eq(1), 'lab1')
group = (df['Label'].eq(0)&df['Label'].ne(df['Label'].shift())).cumsum()

# compute cumcount
df['Csum'] = df.groupby(['ID', group]).cumcount().add(1)
```

output:

```
      ID        Date  Outcome Label  Csum
0   ID_1  2021-01-01        0   0.0     1
1   ID_1  2021-01-02        0   0.0     2
2   ID_1  2021-01-03        0   0.0     3
3   ID_1  2021-01-04        0   0.0     4
4   ID_1  2021-01-05        0   0.0     5
5   ID_1  2021-01-06        0  lab1     6
6   ID_1  2021-01-07        0  lab1     7
7   ID_1  2021-01-08        1  lab1     8
8   ID_1  2021-01-09        0   0.0     1
9   ID_1  2021-01-10        0   0.0     2
10  ID_1  2021-01-11        0   0.0     3
11  ID_2  2021-01-01        0  lab1     1
12  ID_2  2021-01-02        0  lab1     2
13  ID_2  2021-01-03        1  lab1     3
14  ID_2  2021-01-04        0   0.0     1
15  ID_2  2021-01-05        0   0.0     2
16  ID_2  2021-01-06        0   0.0     3
17  ID_2  2021-01-07        0  lab1     4
18  ID_2  2021-01-08        0  lab1     5
19  ID_2  2021-01-09        1  lab1     6
20  ID_2  2021-01-10        0   0.0     1
21  ID_2  2021-01-11        0   0.0     2
```